# Hunch.com Style Questions Database. Any F/OSS datasets available?

Tags: open-source, dataset, social-networking

Anyone know of a [www.Hunch.com](http://hunch.com) style questions database that helps users with their "taste" graph. Preferably Free & Open-source.

If there is none in existence, would the community be interested in creating a crowd-sourced project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used Amazon Mechnical Turk to crowdsource this.